# `getByRole` can't find the name of the appropriate textbox

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Here is the test for the :

```js
  it("changes the state when body input is changed", () => {
    render(<CommentForm />)
    // let input = screen.getByLabelText("Your Name");

    let input = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Your Comment" });
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "MyComment" } });
    expect(input.value).toEqual("MyComment");
  });
```

With the commented line it works (when I search with `getByLabelText`). Here is what I am getting when I try to find it with `getByRole`:

```
 Unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name "Your Comment"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      document:

      Name "":
      <body />

      --------------------------------------------------
      generic:

      Name "":
      <div />

      Name "":
      <div
        class="input-group"
      />

      Name "":
      <div
        class="input-group"
      />

      --------------------------------------------------
      heading:

      Name "Post a Comment":
      <h2 />

      --------------------------------------------------
      textbox:

      Name "Your Name":
      <input
        id="author-name"
        name="author"
        type="text"
        value=""
      />

      Name "":
      <textarea
        cols="30"
        id="body"
        name="body"
        rows="10"
      />
```

So it seems like the name is empty but I am not sure why that is.

And here is the actual component:

```js
import React from "react";
import useInput from "../hooks/useInput";

const CommentForm = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const { value: author, reset: resetAuthor, bind: bindAuthor } = useInput("");
  const { value: body, reset: resetBody, bind: bindBody } = useInput("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmit({ author, body }, resetInputs);
  };
  const resetInputs = () => {
    resetAuthor();
    resetBody();
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Post a Comment</h2>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="author-name">Your Name</label>
        <input id="author-name" type="text" name="author" {...bindAuthor} />
      </div>

      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="body">Your Comment</label>
        <textarea
          id="body"
          name="body"
          cols="30"
          rows="10"
          {...bindBody}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CommentForm;
```

Can anyone see the issue here. I am sure it should work and I don't see any reason why the author input can be grabbed with `getByRole` and name but this one can't.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `<label htmlFor>` is incorrect.  Because you've given `htmlFor`, `id` and `body` the same values the DOM is getting confused and assigning the label content ("Your Comment") as the name. It's working with author by accident.

So:

```
<label htmlFor="author-name">Your Name</label>
<input id="author-name" type="text" name="author" />
```

Should be able to be checked with:

```
screen.getByRole('textbox', {name: author})
```

For the `textarea` if you do:

```
<label htmlFor="body">Your Comment</label>
<textarea
   id="body"
   name="bodyInput"
>
```

Then:

```
screen.getByRole('textarea', {name: body})
```

Should give you the result you're looking for.

Notice in both cases I'm checking the element's `name` value in the element where `id` matches the value of `htmlFor`. I am *not* checking the value of the `<label>` text itself.

Comment: the role for a textarea is not textarea, but textbox :/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/textbox_role

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem when using a React Hook Form Controller for a Material UI TextField. Even though my TextField element had a label prop, no `aria-label` value was present in the HTML until I added the `inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Email" }}` prop to the TextField component.

Note: the aria-label is the value that the getByRole "name" actually refers to in this case. See [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/) for details.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  id="email"
  name="email"
  render={({ onChange, ref }) => (
    <TextField
      autoComplete="email"
      className={classes.textField}
      error={Boolean(errors.email)}
      fullWidth
      helperText={errors.email && errors.email.message}
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Email" }}
      inputRef={ref}
      label="Email"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )}
  rules={{
    pattern: {
      message: "invalid email address",
      value: EMAIL_REGEX,
    },
    required: true,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your `textarea` has `name=body`, and you're looking for `name=Your Comment`. Try to use `body` instead.

Comment: But when I search for input author I do almost exactly the same :

`let input = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Your Name" });`

And it finds the correct input